# Why can I assign struct functions to members of other structs?

Tags: go

I was just messing around and wrote the below piece of code,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    name string
}

func (p Person) printName() {
    fmt.Println(p.name)
}

type Man struct {
    name string
    f func()
}

func main() {
    p := Person{name: "John"}
    m := Man{name: "Adam"}
    m.f = p.printName
    p.printName()
    m.f()
}
```

The above code results in the following output. This works across packages too.

```
John
John
```

So, here are my questions.

1. Why does this work?
2. Struct methods require receivers of the same type. How is the function still able to access members of the Person struct?
3. What happens when `m.f = p.printName` is executed in the above example?

Comment: minor typo but printName is not exported yet appears to be called as PrintName further down.

Comment: Oops! My bad. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question deals mostly with receivers and may extend a bit to embedding.
From the [relevant section of the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

> A method is a function with a receiver. A method declaration binds an
>   identifier, the method name, to a method, and associates the method
>   with the receiver's base type.
>
> MethodDecl = "func" Receiver MethodName Signature [ FunctionBody ] .
>
> Receiver   = Parameters .
>
> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the
>   method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic
>   parameter, the receiver. Its type must be of the form T or *T
>   (possibly using parentheses) where T is a type name. The type denoted
>   by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be a pointer or
>   interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the
>   method. The method is said to be bound to the base type and the method
>   name is visible only within selectors for type T or *T.
>
> A non-blank receiver identifier must be unique in the method
>   signature. If the receiver's value is not referenced inside the body
>   of the method, its identifier may be omitted in the declaration. The
>   same applies in general to parameters of functions and methods.
>
> For a base type, the non-blank names of methods bound to it must be
>   unique. If the base type is a struct type, the non-blank method and
>   field names must be distinct.
>
> Given type Point, the declarations
>
> ```
> func (p *Point) Length() float64 {    
>    return math.Sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y *p.y) 
> }
>
> func (p *Point) Scale(factor float64) {   
>    p.x *= factor  
>    p.y *= factor
> }
> ```
>
> bind the methods Length and Scale, with receiver type *Point, to the
>   base type Point.
>
> **The type of a method is the type of a function with the receiver as
>   first argument.**
>
> For instance, the method Scale has type
>
> func(p *Point, factor float64)
>
> However, a function declared this way is not a method.

Man has a field named f that is a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing. 
As we saw above golang internally treats

```
func (p Person) printName()
```

as

```
func printName(p Person)
```

and this can be considered as a function of no arguments when it acts on a Person struct (and it does because p is a Person and p.printName acts on p). Therefore it is allowed to be assigned to Man.f

So the moment you assigned the f field on the Man struct to a function that has captured the Person instance with name "John" and reads the name from that, therefore you get effect of the second "John" being printed. 
The Man.name field has never come into play on that one.

I suspect that what you would expect as normal behaviour can be achieved with struct embedding of Person into a Man.

[here is a playground link to demonstrate that](https://play.golang.com/p/tW77WCMY6iZ)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)

Comment: no worries! here are two more docs to help you with tricky aspects of golang from the effective go series:
a) [ponter vs value receivers](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values)
b) [struct embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :)

I understand why Man.f can be assigned Person.printName.

    When you say "So the moment you assigned the f field on the Man struct to a function that has captured the Person instance with name "John" and reads the name from that, therefore you get effect of the second "John" being printed.", do you mean that the Man.f basically points to the Method-table of person?

Comment: yes, and not of any Person, but of a copy of the p Person which has name as "john" . [here is another playground example](https://play.golang.com/p/Sagb-edSBP3) that demonstrates the pass by value / pass by reference aspect of that first argument that is the struct where the method acts upon.

Comment: Interesting. This can lead to some weird behavior, where functions of nullified struct object pointer can still be accessed as the underlying object is not going to be garbage collected -- [see this code sample](https://play.golang.org/p/E7CIulvgYEg)

I can't think of a reason that this was an intended feature of the language, rather I guess this is just a side effect.

Comment: it is very ill advised to try and outsmart the golang garbage collector. You should never equate structs to nil hoping that you trigger a collect. In the case you showed it correctly does not collect it cause it's smart enough to keep the correct reference count (you have that pointer being used by m.f which is still in scope. The correct approach is to keep the scope of your variables as small as possible and to have short lived goroutines.

Answer (score 2):

A method, in Go, is basically a function with a `receiver`. That receiver is wraped by the compiler, and beyond that, there is nothing more different from a normal function. That means, at anywhere, the method always gets the receiver which it is bound to, no matter how you call it, assign it to another variable or anythiing else.

In your code, `f` is **not** a method of type `Man`. It is merely a field of type `func()`. You can set to anything that match the signature, and the function will know nothing about `Man` or its instance. That means, `m.f` has no knowledge of `m` and no access to `m.name` or any other field of `m`.

And a note, you can call methods like: `Person.PrintName(p)` where p is of type `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

function in Golang is also a value, it can be passed as parameter or assigned by other function too, method in Golang is also a function, with one different, it has receiver in it's value, so when use assign a method to a function (which have same signature) it's refer to the receiver and executing code in that method to destination function